# Automatically Add Default Text Into WordPress Post Editor For Existing and New Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, editor

I am trying to create a function that will automatically add default text into the WordPress Post Editor for existing and new posts. I already found code to add_filter to default_content and that works well for new posts, but will not have any affect on existing, published posts/pages. The new default text could be added when I press "Update" to existing posts, that would be fine.

Here is what I have so far:

```
function add_before_content($content) {
 $content = '<p>My default content.</p>';
return $content;
}
add_action('publish_post', 'add_before_content');
add_action('update_post', 'add_before_content');
add_filter('default_content', 'add_before_content');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Filters and actions send different parameters to their functions, so you can't necessarily use the same function for different ones. Check the filter/action references for the right parameters for each.

Also, there is no update_post action. Maybe you wanted save_post.

But actions are probably not what you want to use anyway. They are good for doing something related to the subject of the action, but to deal with content you're better off using filters.

For example, something like the following might do what you want:

```
function add_before_content( $content ) {
  $my_content = '<p>My default content.</p>';
  if (substr($content, 0, strlen($my_content)) != $my_content) {
      $content = $my_content . $content;
  }
  return $content;
}
add_filter( 'content_save_pre', 'add_before_content', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Thanks so much @bobdye this is working perfectly. Is there any way to reduce the lag time (before WP recognizes any edits to $my_content) and remove/replace the existing $my_content, if $my_content should be updated from functions.php? For example, if I had an ad banner with a URL and then changed it later in functions.php?